# Show that $\sin(x)$ is differentiable with $\sin(x)$ as series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, trigonometry

Given the series $$\sin(x) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n + 1)!}} $$
Show that $\sin(x)$ is differentiable.

I tried this:

$$ \frac{\sin(x) - \sin(x_0)}{x - x_0} = \Biggl(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n + 1)!}}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n}x_0^{2n+1}}{(2n + 1)!}}\Biggr)\frac{1}{x-x_0}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{x^{2n+1}-x_0^{2n+1}}{x - x_0}\right)\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n + 1)!}}
$$

But I am stuck at this point.
Does anyone know the trick?

Edit: more simplified:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(x^{2n}-x_0^{2n})\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n + 1)!}}$$
and now with lim

$$\lim_{x_0 \to x} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(x^{2n}-x_0^{2n})\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n + 1)!}}=0$$

Where is my mistake? What am I missing?

Comment: Apply the limit and justify bringing it into the series. What happens then?

Comment: @Clayton I did, please take a look. I edited the question.

Comment: You need to check your arithmetic (simplified incorrectly) and have not applied the limit inside the series (hence the suggestion to justify bringing it into the series).

Comment: Show that the series of differentiated summands converges uniformly on any compact set.  The differentiate under the series.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^{2n+1}-x_0^{2n+1}}{x-x_0}\right)\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\big({x^{2n}+x^{2n-1}x_0^{}+\ldots+xx_0^{2n-1}+x_0^{2n}}\big)\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}$$

but $x\to x_0$, then:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\big({x^{2n}+x^{2n-1}x_0^{}+\ldots+xx_0^{2n-1}+x_0^{2n}}\big)\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\to\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+1)x_0^{2n}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n x_0^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\cos(x_0)$$

Comment: It seems you lost some of your $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$ symbols. Also, should not one of your equals signs be "$\to$"?

Comment: @311411, you are absolutely right.

Comment: How do you justify the interchange of the limit and summation operators? That is the non-trivial part of the proof.

Comment: great answer! thanks a lot.